# How to sort numbers from high to low without looking if it's negative or positive

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
sortByAmountHighToLow(trades) {
  return trades.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.total - a.total;
  });
},
```

I have this right now (in Vue) which sorts an array of numbers from high to low, as it should.

What I instead need is a sorting function which does not look at negative numbers differently from positive numbers.

This is the output I would like (high to low):
[-531, 245, -195, 54, -12]

I'm getting:
[245, 54, -12, -195, -513]

I hope this clearly explains what I need.

Comment: In other words... `Math.abs()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that the original functions treats negatives differently

But this it what you want:

```js
const array = [245, 54, -12, -195, -513]

array.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(b) - Math.abs(a))

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
trades.sort((a, b) => {
  return Math.abs(b) - Math.abs(a);  
});
```